# Express/Webpack/React : How to ship different client-side apps depending on the endpoint?

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to understand how Express and Webpack can be used together to ship out different...

1) client-side js bundles

2) index.html

3) other static resources

...depending on the Express endpoint that is hit.

Modularizing:

I see how Express can modularize server code based on the routing and that Webpack can do code splitting, but I can't quite fit the 2 together to send completely different apps based on the endpoint.

Like I would imagine a solution like this:

**The File Structure in Express:**

```
/app
 -app.html
 /public
  -bundle.js 

/app2
 -app2.html
 /public
  -bundle2.js
```

**app.js**

```
app.use("/app1", express.static(__dirname + "/app1/public/"));

app.use("/app2", express.static(__dirname + "/app2/public2"));

app.get('/app', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app1/app1.html');
});

app.get('/app2', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app2/app2.html');
});
```

Yet, I haven't seen any reputable examples doing something like this - which usually means I'm doing something wrong. haha

**What I have seen:**

-Webpack code splitting examples that use the same public folder(how do you ship out different statics?)

-Since I'm using React - most examples are mingled server-side strategies(isomorphic) and/or use Jade(which makes it hard to imagine how create a splitting structure for a purely client-side js strategy).

**Question:**

Is there a standardized way to structure the client-side coding split I'm describing with Webpack and Express?

Answer (score 0):

Express makes a very brief [mention](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.mountpath) of a sub-app:

```
var express = require('express');

// app 1
var app1 = express();
app1.use("/", express.static('app1'));

// app 2
var app2 = express();
app2.use("/", express.static('app2'));

// main app
var app = express();
app.use('/app1', app1);
app.use('/app2', app2);

app.listen(3000);
```

Express [mentions](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) also writing a separate middleware and routing system:

```
var express = require('express');

// app 1
var app1 = express.Router();
app1.use("/", express.static('app1'));

// app 2
var app2 = express.Router();
app2.use("/", express.static('app2'));

// main app
var app = express();

app.use('/app1', app1);
app.use('/app2', app2);

app.listen(3000);
```